# Makefile not updating one particular file

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a makefile which works fine for all other files, but not for the `main.cpp` file. When I change the `main.cpp` file, it does not update `main.o`.

here is the makefile:

```
CXX = g++
SRCF = main.cpp Animal.cpp
SRC = $(addprefix src/, $(SRCF))

VER = Debug
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++17
EXE = Animal
OBJF = $(subst .cpp,.o, $(SRCF))
OBJ = $(addprefix src/obj/, $(OBJF) )
#PKG = `pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2`


$(VER)/$(EXE) : $(OBJ)
    $(CXX)  $(CXXFLGS) -o $@ $< $(PKG)

src/obj/%.o:src/%.cpp src/%.h
    $(CXX)  $(CXXFLGS) -c -o $@ $< $(PKG)

clean:
    rm -rf $(EXE) $(OBJ)

print-%  : ; @echo $* = $($*)
```

When I change `Animal.h` or `Animal.cpp` it updates `Animals.o` and the `Animal` executable. But why does it **not work for `main`** ?? I have specified how to update `main.o` in this line :-

```
src/obj/%.o:src/%.cpp src/%.h
    $(CXX)  $(CXXFLGS) -c -o $@ $< $(PKG)
```

Please help me and thanks it advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Introduction to Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html#Pattern-Intro) section of GNU Make's manual:

> In order for the pattern rule to apply, its target pattern must match the file name under consideration and **all of its prerequisites (after pattern substitution) must name files that exist or can be made**.

Therefore, if there is no `src/main.h` (or can't be made), the following pattern rule will not match against `src/obj/main.o`:

```
src/obj/%.o: src/%.cpp src/%.h
    $(CXX)  $(CXXFLGS) -c -o $@ $< $(PKG)
```

You need an additional pattern rule without the `src/%.h` prerequisite:

```
 src/obj/%.o: src/%.cpp
        $(CXX)  $(CXXFLGS) -c -o $@ $< $(PKG)
```

Comment: Can you explain *why* make need the second line without the '%.h' clause? I can't get the point! Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer with the relevant reference to the manual.

Comment: I still can't get the point! Why the clause "src/%.h" prevents make to build main.o again when main.cpp has changed? If there is no main.h or can be craeted, make will throw an error message. But OP did not tell us something about an error. He tolds us only that the rule does not match...

Comment: thanks :) . It compiling but now giving linker error.But main problem is gone; Thanks again for the help Sir

Comment: In that rule above `%` is replaced by `main`. Therefore, after pattern substitution `src/main.h` becomes a prerequisite. Since it neither exists nor can be build the pattern rule doesn't apply.

Comment: Each of the other `.cpp` files has a counterpart `.h` file and therefore that pattern rule does apply.

Comment: Got it sir : ) XD

Comment: @Klaus with the posted makefile it's not possible to generate `main.o` at all. Probably OP already had a previously generated `main.o` (either manually or by means of a previous version of that makefile) and the effect OP saw was just that `main.o` wasn't being updated.